# How to use a custom tangent for anisotropic shading in BI/Blend4Web?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, shaders, blend4web

I'd like to create a material such as this in Blend4Web (and if it can be done in BI, chances seem good the same approach can be adapted for Blend4Web):

[image]

I've rendered the above image in cycles via a tiled tangent texture plugged into into the *Tangent* input of an *Anisotropic* shader:

[image]

Unfortunately, while BI does have a tangent shading option, I can't find a way to control the tangent direction quite so easily in BI. Is this sort of thing possible? How can it be done?

Here's the .blend with the shader for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The only way (at that moment) to create anisotropic effect (with such texture like your) is to imitate it by adding fake specular over the normal map especialy baked for such material.

[image] Heres the example of such imitation that works in blend4web.